# Return data in a query view based on whether a table is empty or not

Tags: sql, sql-server, view

I want to query one of two tables depending whether one of the tables have data. For instance i have two tables one called Prev and another called Init_SS. If there is data in the Prev table then  the query should return all the data in the Prev table, otherwise if the Prev table is empty, then all the data in the Init_SS table must be returned.

I am using SQL Server with the SQL Server Mangement Studio and this is the code i used in my query view:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Prev) SELECT * FROM Prev ELSE SELECT * FROM Init_SS
```

When i press the execute sql button it does exactly what i want, returning the one of the tables based on whether Prev is empty or not. But when i try to save the query view i get the following error message:

```
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'IF'
```

So it seems i can't use 'IF' in a query view. How can i create a query view by letting it do what i descibe above?

I also tried this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Prev) SELECT * FROM Prev ELSE SELECT * FROM Init_SS) as tb
```

Comment: do u have same fields in both the tables???

Comment: No, both tables does not have the same fields. If the Init_SS data is pulled then extra calculated fileds will be added.

Answer (score 1):

If the both tables have similar design, you can do

```
SELECT * FROM Prev 
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM Init_SS where not exists (SELECT 1 FROM Prev)
```

Answer (score 0):

you could do something like this

```
SELECT * FROM Prev          --<-- Select all
IF(@@ROWCOUNT = 0)          --<-- If no rows has been returned
BEGIN 
 SELECT * FROM Init_SS       --<-- Select this 
END
```

This will not be possible iside a view. you can use a stored procedure of a table value function for this.

A view can only have a single simple Select statement inside it.